# Appending date to HTML Redirect URL using Variable

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, url-rewriting

Looking to append yesterdays date to a URL in a meta html redirect. The goal would be something that works like this.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=xxx&q="news" after:%yesterdaydate%"/>
```

Would this be possible with Javascript or HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply.

After creating a Date, create a date string for yesterday's date.

Set the `<meta>` tag - page will redirect to that URL.

NOTE: It would be prudent to do this by creating the `<meta>` tag programmatically rather than using `innerHTML`, but this will work to demonstrate how it is done.

```js
const date = new Date();
const dateString = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-1)).toLocaleDateString();
const meta = `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=xxx&q=news after:${dateString}"/>`;
document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += meta;
```